# a disposed closure has a strange behavior

Tags: c#, closures, idisposable

I have a disposable class like this :

```
public class Person:IDisposable
{
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public void Dispose()
    {}
}
```

and here's a set of extensions methods that returns a default value if the caller is null:

```
static class Extensions
{

    public class Option<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T> _resultGetter;

        public bool HasValue { get; }

        public Option(Func<T> resultGetter, bool hasValue)
        {
            _resultGetter = resultGetter;
            HasValue = hasValue;
        }

        public T Value => _resultGetter();
    }

    public static Option<TResult> SafeGetter<T, TResult>(this T self, Func<T, TResult> getter, Func<TResult> defaultGetter = null) where T : class
    {
        defaultGetter = defaultGetter ?? (() => default(TResult));
        return new Option<TResult>(self == null ? defaultGetter :()=> getter(self),self!=null);
    }
}
```

As you can see the `SafeGetter` method returns an `Option` object that has a getter function that has a `self` parameter as closure.

So to test the getter function after an object is disposed I wrote a test like this :

```
public void SafeGetterDisposableTest()
{
    Extensions.Option<string> nameGetter; 
    using (var john = new Person { Name = "John" })
    {
        nameGetter = john.SafeGetter(x => x.Name);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(nameGetter.Value);
}
```

as you can see I have got the Option object and call it after john is disposed. I thought that I would get an exception but to my surprise the test is working.
Why this is happening ? Does this code somehow introduce memory leak ?

Comment: As an aside, and what your answers are hinting at, please properly implement `IDisposable`, see [Implementing IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @RonBeyer That assumes that the type holds a direct link to an unmanaged resource, rather than having a field that is a managed reference that is itself `IDisposable`.  It's *very* uncommon to write a class in the former position, it's *extremely* common to write a class in the latter position.  The *vast* majority of `IDisposable` classes should not be following that pattern.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure I follow you, even with a class that does not have an unmanaged resource, and is managing disposable resources, the implementation above (maybe I gave the wrong link?) can still be used to ensure that `.Dispose()` is called on the managed classes, and that it is called only once.

Comment: @RonBeyer All you need to do if you have an `IDisposable` object that composes another `IDisposable` object is dispose of that object in the `Dispose` method, and possibly also track whether the object has been disposed, and you're done.  Creating a finalizer, having a `Dispose(bool)` method,, etc. is all entirely inappropriate in such a context

Comment: @Servy I completely agree about the finalizer, but having a `protected void Dispose(bool)` shouldn't be considered inappropriate in a class that is not sealed, if it were a sealed class, I would agree, but I think in unsealed classes it clarifies operation rather than have that one-time logic in the `Dispose` method.

Comment: @RonBeyer The purpose of having the method is to separate out disposal of managed vs. unmanaged objects.  If you have only managed objects, there's nothing to distinguish between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that I would get an exception but to my surprise the test is
>   working.

You do not receive an `ObjectDisposedException` (or any other exception for that matter) just by simply implementing `IDisposable`. Your `Dispose` method is *empty*, and doesn't alter the object even after it has been called by your `using` statement. If you alter it to throw an exception in your getter after the object has been disposed, you'll get an exception. Otherwise, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

It is a *convention* that `IDisposable` objects be implemented such that they'll throw an exception when their members are accesses after they've been disposed.  This is not behavior of the language.  If your disposable object actually had an umanaged resource that it was using, and then cleaned up, then presumably an operation you perform after its been disposed wouldn't work properly, even if you didn't explicitly throw, hence the convention.